# Change the font size of attributed text label xcode iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel, font-size, nsattributedstring, uifont

I am working on changing the font size of attributed and non attributed label texts.
I want to scan all the `UIlabel` in my `UIView` then based on whether they are attributed text holder I want to increase the font size of entire label while preserving the current font attributes like bold, italic, color etc.

```
if ([vv isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
     {
       UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)vv;
       NSDictionary *attributes = [(NSAttributedString *)lbl.attributedText 
       attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];
       if(attributes)
       {
        lbl.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lbl.text
        attributes:attributes];
        lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[UIFontDescriptor
        fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:attributes] 
        size:lbl.font.pointSize+self.fontsize];
       }
    }
```

Using the below line of code I end up skipping the text attributes and it picks the very first font name and apply to the rest of string in label's text

```
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[lbl.font fontName] size:lbl.font.pointSize+self.fontsize];
```

I want to increase font size yet maintain the font attributes 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping Through NSAttributedString Attributes to Increase Font SIze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386849/looping-through-nsattributedstring-attributes-to-increase-font-size)

Comment: Create a mutable copy of the attributes dictionary and get the `NSFontAttributeName` "font value" out of that and if that's non-`nil`, create a new font from the "font value" with increased size.  Then replace the `NSFontAttributeName` entry and re-apply the attributes to the attributed string.