# Attributed text swift how to retain font color with <font color=.." tag

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to use Android's resources in iOS app.
I have a text in xml:

```
<string name="myText"><![CDATA[<h2><font color="#aa2c2c">Some RED header text</font></h2><br /><br />

<font color="#aa2c2c">Red again</font>then back to normal <br /><br />]]></string>
```

I'm implementing night/day option for text. The thing is - when I change textView.textColor to black or white - it changes everything including red text.But I want red to remain red and unattributed text to be what I set it to be programmatically.
In Android textView.setTextColor method for Spanned text  changes only unattributed text. I want the same thing in iOS

this is how the text is set :

```
let text = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: resources.getString(resId).dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)
        tv.attributedText = text;
```

Comment: You have to enumerate the attributes looking for `NSForegroundAttributeName` and change that color manually.

Comment: @Larme could you please write an answer how to do it, I'm really new to iOS dev

Comment: I won't have a perfect code in Swift (I don't use Swift, only Objective-C), but it's like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386849/looping-through-nsattributedstring-attributes-to-increase-font-size

Comment: @Larme but.. what should i do with this attributes? I need red to stay red and others to be as I set for textColor